# Working on remote server

Tags: ssh, ide, editor, sublimetext2, remote-server

My OS: Windows 8

Virtualbox guest:  Ubuntu 12.10 server

I configured apache server on vbox guest and mapped http, https, ssh port successfully into ubuntu server. It works nice without any problem.

I tried several IDEs like PHPStorm, Netbeans, editors like Sublime, all they do is to copy whole project from server, edit on local machine then sync back.

But it is not what I need. I want to work directly on guest server using ssh/sftp connection. I know that notepad++ has this functionality but I love sublime look and feel.

Is there any way to work on guest server with sublime or any other ide for free? (There is sftp solution but it's paid and works just like other ide's, not directly on guest machine) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can choose from, you will probably select the second one:

1. Use the KDE desktop environment (yes, it also exists for MS Windows). It features so called 'kio-slaves' which allow to use *any* protocol out there as if you were doing local file system operations. That means when using a KDE editor like 'kate' or even a whole IDE like 'kdevelop4' you can simply say "open file/project" and not only choose a local file, but something like sftp://server/path/file and start working. The network stuff is handled transparently by the environment, it is fully network transparent. This is how systems should be like. I think the GNOME environment had something similar, but it probably has been removed with version 3 of GNOME.
2. You can 'mount' the guests file system into your MS-Windows file system. not sure about the details how this works in MS-Windows, but I am sure that at least newer versions of MS-Windows have gained such feature. Most likely you are still limited to creating something like a "network harddrive" or something, in other systems (linux, unix, macOS) you can mount whereever in the file system you like. You can use any protocol for this, as long as it is supported by the mounting tools of your local system. 
   Again two options:

   2.a You mount the whole virtual disk. Easy, but might be a problem if that disk is currently used by the guest system.

   2.b You export the virtual disk by starting some server in the virtual system: samba is most likely your choice. Then you can mount that smb file export inside your MS-Windows system and start hacking.

Have fun!